# Prove some facts about the space of continuous functions in the interval $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the following:

Let  be the sequence of functions in $C([0,1])$ given by
$$\displaystyle f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\sqrt n & 0\le x<\dfrac{1}{n}\\\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x} & \dfrac{1}{n}\le x\le 1.\end{cases}$$
Then $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_1)$ that does not converge. Thus, $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_1)$ is not complete.

So to prove that it is Cauchy I did the following:

$$\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x)|+\int_{0}^{1}|f_m(x)|=\int_{0}^{1/n}|\sqrt(n)|+\int_{1/n}^{1}|1/ \sqrt(x)|+\int_{0}^{1/m}|\sqrt(m)|+\int_{1/m}^{1}|1/ \sqrt(x)|=1/\sqrt(n)+1/\sqrt(m)+(2-2/\sqrt(n))+(2-1/\sqrt(m))=4-(1/\sqrt(n)+1/\sqrt(m))$$

So the thing is, I think there is something wrong here since I can't bound $1/\sqrt(n)+1/\sqrt(m)$ as both $n,m$ goes to zero, and the norm could be negative since $1/\sqrt(n)+1/\sqrt(m)$ could be larger that 4.

Now another thing, How can I prove that is not convergent?.

And finally, I was trying to figure out **if $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_2)$ is complete?** but the thing is that proving it should be worse that rearrange the above function to give a counter example, but Am I right?.

Can someone help with this questions please?

Comment: Actually $n$ is tending to infinity, not zero. But never mind that. You start by saying $||f_n-f_m||\le||f_n||+||f_m||$, and that's never going to work. Instead, start by considering where the two functions are the same! You can say $\int_0^1|f_n-f_m| = \int_0^?|f_n-f_m|\le\int_0^?|f_n|+\int_0^?|f_m|$ and _that_ will tend to zero...

Comment: Hint: If $n<m$, $f_n-f_m$ is only non-zero on the interval $[0,1/n]$, so
$$
\|f_n - f_m\|_1 = \int_0^{1/m} |\sqrt{n} -\sqrt{m}| + \int_{1/m}^{1/n} |\sqrt{n}-x|
$$

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let $n \wedge m := \min \{n,m\}$ and let $n \vee m := \max \{ n,m \}$ for all integers $n,m \geq 1$.

We may do it softly. Note that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |f_{n} - f_{m}| = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n \vee m}} | \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{m}| dx + \int_{\frac{1}{n \vee m}}^{\frac{1}{n \wedge m}} | \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{n \wedge m} | dx \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n \vee m} + \frac{\sqrt{m}}{n \vee m} + 2\frac{1}{n \wedge m} + 2\frac{1}{n \vee m} + \frac{\sqrt{n \wedge m}}{n \wedge m} + \frac{\sqrt{n \wedge m}}{n \vee m} \to 0
$$
as $m,n$ grows.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), and how can you prove that it doesn't converge?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and choose $N >\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$. Then for $n > m > N$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^1 f_n(x) - f_m(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_0^1 f_m(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left(\int_0^{1/n} \sqrt{n} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x\right) - \left(\int_0^{1/n} \sqrt{n} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} + 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \right) - \left (\frac{\sqrt{m}}{m} + 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{m}}   \right ) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt n} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt m} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{m}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt m} - \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \\
&< \frac{1}{\sqrt m} < \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
showing the sequence is Cauchy w.r.t. $||\cdot||_1.$ Now suppose $f_n$ has limit $f \in C([0,1])$. Then $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ on $(0,1)$, which cannot be extended continuously onto $[0,1]$. Thus the space is incomplete.

Comment: Answering the latter part of your question, $C([0,1])$ is incomplete w.r.t. $|| \cdot ||_p$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$ (the inequality excludes the sup norm). Some solutions are given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156904/showing-that-the-space-c0-1-with-the-l-1-norm-is-incomplete

Comment: Thanks a lot of this, then we can not extend continously f because we are allowed to reach zero which is infinite right? and why $f(x)=1/ \sqrt(x)$

Comment: More formally, there is a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $f(x_n)$ is unbounded. The reasoning $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ should be clear from plots of $f_n$ for large $n$. If you consider $f_n$ over the interval $[a,1]$  any $0 < a < 1$, the limit is exactly $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$. Letting $a \to 0$, we necessarily have $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, le me check it out, If I get stuck, can I let you know, here is late, so it will be tomorrow :)

Comment: Why do we can forget the absolute value in the integral?

Comment: We let $n > m$.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot, now, If the functions are complex valued, Does the proof change?

Comment: How can you argue that the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}$

Comment: And well it can't converge :) right that is what we want to prove, my definition of completeness is different right?

Comment: The proof is specifically for the $f_n$ described in the question but shows a counterexample to how the space of real, continuous functions on a compact interval is incomplete in the $||\cdot||_1$ norm. If we ask the question "is the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb C$ complete wrt $||\cdot||_1$", the answer is no, and we can just use this example since the imaginary part of the function is 0. And no, the limit as $n \to \infty$ does not exist! On the interval $[a,1]$, $a > 0$, the limit is $1/\sqrt x$, but we cannot extend any further (see previous comment).

Comment: Thanks Nitin but the thing is that I want to prove that $C([0,1])$ is not complete, therefore the sequences given above should not converge, this is it does not have to be getting close to anything so how can you prove in detail that this funtion is not close to some number :) thaat is my question

Comment: The sequence does not converge in the space $C([0,1])$. This was made very clear in the previous comments. Also, the function is not going to be close to 'some number' -- if the sequence were to converge, it would be 'close' to some *function* in the sense that the integral of the difference between the functions is very small for large $n$. In this case, we *assume* there is a limit and derive a contradiction, the contradiction being that the closest possible limit is not continuous on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ok give me some minutes right an I will be back :)